# How do `if` and `if-else` differ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I get different results when using `if-else` statement in the following ways:

```
// #1
if (condition) {
   doOneThing();
}
doAnotherThing();

// #2
if (condition) {
   doOneThing();
} else {
   doAnotherThing();
}
```

Could anybody please explain how they are different?

Comment: Maybe you can show actual code and what explain what you see is different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the programmer and I'm Asian. So my english and my programming knowledge is so basic. If anybody would like to suggest anything about wording and programming, please share. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this with a lot of assumptions that I understand your question. Basically, if you're doing ...

```
if (condition1) {
  doSomethingCool();
}
doSomethingNice();
```

... the program sees `doSomethingCool` as optional - only calls it if `condition1` check passes, but `doSomethingNice` will get called every time because there's no *check* for/around it.

If you're doing ...

```
if (condition1) {
  doSomethingCool();
} else {
  doSomethingNice();
}
```

... only one of those will get called because when the program checks `condition1`, it will call either `doSomethingCool` **or** `doSomethingNice`.